# Unexpected "[" in line of code

Tags: php, html

For some reason i'm getting an unexpected "[" in the below line of code. I'm not an expert at php so it could be something simple and i'm not seeing it.

```
<span class=\"url\"> ". ereg_replace("[","",$ads]['ad_url'][$idx]) ."</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$ads['ad_desc'][$idx] ."</div>
```

Thxs for the help in advance

I'm now getting the error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING** after updating the a partial part of the code above to

```
preg_replace("/[/","",$ads['ad_url'][$idx])
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is the full updated code

```
 <span class=\"url\"> ".a ereg_replace("\[","",$ads['ad_url'][$idx]) ."</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$ads['ad_desc'][$idx] .</div>v>
```

Comment: the `]` directly after `$ads` is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a slash before [ in ereg param .. and replace ereg_replace with preg_replace (ereg is deprecated) then remove the ] after $ads like this:

```
ereg_replace("\[","",$ads['ad_url'][$idx])
```

better:
     preg_replace("/\[/","",$ads['ad_url'][$idx])

Comment: That seemed to of worked by now i'm getting "syntax error, unexpected T_STRING"

Comment: Immediately before [ you need a backslash: \, which is not a slash: /. It is an escape character. You can see it in the code by kappa, which is correct.  Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash

Answer (score 0):

There is a closing bracket `]` after the first occurrence of `$ads` which shouldn't be there.

Further on your regular expression (the first argument of `ereg_repalce`) contains a control character that has to be expressed with a backlsash like this: `\[`. (Also note, that `ereg_replace` is deprecated and you should use `preg_replace`<sup>[documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)</sup>.)

And at the start and the very end there are double quotes missing. But I assume you just didn't copy them.